# How can I design a gridview type of view inside a cardview and implement it in code?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, nestedrecyclerview

I have already made the recyclerView and I can't figure out how to design the cardview . As it has 4 custom items inside it .

How can I get the access to the card items?

[image: img]

In my cardview design layout where I have placed a gridview inside the cardview and i can't figure out how to access the gridview items with an ArrayList.

My cardview design layout

```
     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/elevation_height"
android:id="@+id/cvVideos">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@android:drawable/presence_video_busy"
android:id="@+id/ivIconTitle"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle" />
</LinearLayout>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="120dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    tools:listitem="@layout/video_grid_listitem"
    android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
</GridView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Please show the current XML layout and code that you have and what that looks like.

Comment: And what makes you think this needs `CardView` at all? This really looks like a GridLayout of just regular Views.

Comment: I am using recyclerview @cricket_007.

Comment: @Sushrita yes this possible using recyclerView  as well easy to handle.for bottom view you can use bottomsheet

Comment: Layoutmanager can be set as a Grid @Sushrita

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari can you tell me how to get the customized cardview  items of the view  .

Comment: inside card view use Linear layout. inside linear layout use first imageView then textView and then your button for watching vodeo etc etc.then bind your view with recyclerView adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

In the RecyclerView use xml like this:

```
  @Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_XML, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

    return viewHolder;
}
```

Now design your cardView Xml like this:

your_XML.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/content_find_service_providers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="3dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      >

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

But i recommend use **GridView** intsead of cardView

Answer (score 0):

```
    [![You can user this:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/networkCard_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_bottom_spacing"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_left_spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_right_spacing"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/card_top_spacing"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_corner_radius"
        card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
        card_view:cardMaxElevation="0dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/mainLL"
            android:background="@drawable/oval_white_background_5"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/productsLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/productCountTV"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/header_font_size_small"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/gridProductLL1"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/grey_border_without_padding"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/productIV1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_gallery_height"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/crop_tile2" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/product1TitleTV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/greyDark600"
                                android:text="MyTitle"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:visibility="visible" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/gridProductLL2"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/grey_border_without_padding"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/productIV2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_gallery_height"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/crop_tile2" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/product2TitleTV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/greyDark600"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:text="MyTitle"
                                android:visibility="visible" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/gridProductLL3"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/grey_border_without_padding"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/productIV3"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_gallery_height"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/crop_tile2" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/product3TitleTV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/greyDark600"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                android:text="MyTitle"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/productPrice3TV"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:text="Rs. 200"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/product3buysNowTV"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_blue_border_botton"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_facebook"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/gridProductLL4"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/grey_border_without_padding"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.34"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/productIV4"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_gallery_height"
                                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/crop_tile2" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/t5LTVImageCount"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@color/gallery_image_count_background_color"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:visibility="gone" />
                        </RelativeLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/product4TitleTV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:textColor="@color/greyDark600"
                                android:text="MyTitle"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:visibility="visible" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/productPrice4TV"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:text="Rs. 200"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/product4buysNowTV"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_blue_border_botton"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_facebook"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/gridProductLL5"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/grey_border_without_padding"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/productIV5"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/image_gallery_height"
                            android:layout_margin="1dp"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                            android:src="@drawable/crop_tile2" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/product5TitleTV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Product Name"
                                android:textColor="@color/greyDark600"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/productPrice5TV"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/product5buysNowTV"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_blue_border_botton"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_facebook"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/gridProductLL6"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/grey_border_without_padding"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:visibility="gone">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.34"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/productIV6"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/image_gallery_height"
                                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                                android:src="@drawable/crop_tile2" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/t6LTVImageCount"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@color/gallery_image_count_background_color"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:textColor="@color/white"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:visibility="gone" />
                        </RelativeLayout>


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/product6TitleTV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Product Name"
                                android:textColor="@color/greyDark600"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:visibility="gone" />

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/productPrice6TV"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/product6buysNowTV"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_blue_border_botton"
                                    android:gravity="center"
                                    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="2dp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/color_facebook"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size_small"
                                    android:visibility="gone" />
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seeAllTV"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:text="See all Users"
                android:textColor="@color/lite_blue"
                android:textSize="@dimen/header_font_size_small"
                android:visibility="gone" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried it this way but I can't get to manage it properly.

Comment: according you screen short you need like this only rt? where you are facing problem exactly?

Comment: How can I create a holder for this cardview? It's my main concern

Comment: You can have a List<another list of grid view for a single row>, 1 field of your model should be a list like ArrayList<Model> modelList;  and while rendering use as mainList.get(position).get(1).gridviewModel.